# Cygwin: missing stream data due to stdio putc + line buffering

Tags: c, cygwin, stdio, getc

The expected output from the following program is:

```
received REQUEST
 from client
received REPLY
 from server
```

this is seen on, for instance, GNU/Linux. However, on Cygwin the actual output is this:

```
received REQUEST
 from client
received 
 from server
```

An empty line (the `"\n"` string) is received from the stream on the client side instead of `"REPLY\n"`.

The problem stems from the combination of `putc` and line buffering.

- In the `server` function, if we replace `my_puts` with `fprintf`, the expected output is produced.
- In `server`, if we take out the `setvbuf` call which switches the stream to line buffering, the expected output is also produced.
- If we change `my_puts` so that it outputs each character using `fprintf(f, "%c", ch)` instead of `putc(ch, f)`, the expected output is produced.
- Replacing `putc` by `fputc` makes no difference.
- In server, adding a file positioning operation, like `fseek(cli_stream, 0, SEEK_CUR)` between input and output as required by ISO C (thus just before the `my_puts` call) makes no difference. This is included in the code below.

Is this program doing something wrong to bring about this strange issue?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int my_puts(FILE *f, const char *str)
{
   int ch;

   while ((ch = *str++))
     if (putc(ch, f) == EOF) {
       perror("putc");
       return EOF;
     }

   return 0;
}

int client(struct sockaddr_in *srv_addr)
{
  int srv_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  FILE *srv_stream;
  char buf[256];

  if (srv_fd == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (connect(srv_fd, (struct sockaddr *) srv_addr, sizeof *srv_addr) == -1) {
    perror("connect");
    close(srv_fd);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if ((srv_stream = fdopen(srv_fd, "r+")) == 0) {
    perror("fdopen");
    close(srv_fd);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

   setvbuf(srv_stream, (char *) NULL, _IOLBF, 0);

  my_puts(srv_stream, "REQUEST\n");
  fflush(srv_stream);
  shutdown(srv_fd, SHUT_WR);

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, srv_stream) == 0) {
    printf("short fread");
    fclose(srv_stream);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("received %s from server\n", buf);
  return 0;
}

void server(int acc_fd)
{
  struct sockaddr_in claddr;
  socklen_t claddrlen = sizeof claddr;
  int cli_fd = accept(acc_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &claddr, &claddrlen);
  FILE *cli_stream = fdopen(cli_fd, "r+");;
  char buf[256];

  if (cli_fd == -1) {
    perror("accept");
    if (cli_stream)
      fclose(cli_stream);
    return;
  }

  if (cli_stream == 0) {
    perror("fdopen");
    close(cli_fd);
    return;
  }

  setvbuf(cli_stream, (char *) NULL, _IOLBF, 0);

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, cli_stream) == 0) {
    printf("short fread");
    fclose(cli_stream);
    return;
  }

  printf("received %s from client\n", buf);

  fseek(cli_stream, 0, SEEK_CUR);

  my_puts(cli_stream, "REPLY\n");
  fflush(cli_stream);
  fclose(cli_stream);
}

int main(void)
{
  struct sockaddr_in saddr = { 0 };
  int acc_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  pid_t child;

  saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  saddr.sin_port = htons(12345);
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);

  if (acc_fd == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (bind(acc_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof saddr) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (listen(acc_fd, 1) == -1) {
    perror("listen");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  child = fork();

  if (child == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  } else if (child == 0) {
    server(acc_fd);
    _exit(0);
  } else {
    int status;
    int result = client(&saddr);
    kill(child, SIGKILL);
    if (wait(&status) != child) {
      printf("wait problem");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return result;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cygwin git now [has the fix](http://newlib-cygwin.git;a=commit;h=1eb6db6efb29b41d696db97a95aaaeee2b84c768), backported from OpenBSD.

A smaller repro test case was [posted to the mailing list](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-03/msg00180.html).